# Using Gstreamer with Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, gstreamer, kivy

Could somebody point me to an example of building gstreamer powered application with kivy ?
I want to see how kivy handles gstreamer video output and I don't want to use kivy built in functions for video playback I want some example like [this one](http://www.jonobacon.org/2006/08/28/getting-started-with-gstreamer-with-python/)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see how Kivy handles video playback, that's as easy as looking at the sources ([_gstplayer.pyx](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx) [video_gstplayer.py](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/video/video_gstplayer.py)). A GStreamer appsink is used to pass the data back to Kivy for rendering. You're probably not going to find a tutorial on doing this, because the majority of Kivy users will use the built-in functions.